# Error to select max or latest date

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I want to display details that have the latest date. But I have a problem with it. It say "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" Can someone help me?

Below are the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CCSMASTERLISTREVNO, CCSREVCONTENT, CCSPREPAREDREV, 
     CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE

FROM CCS2_TBL_MASTERLIST 

WHERE CCSEQUIPMENTDPMT = :DPMT 

AND CCSMASTERLISTREVNO <= :REVNO 

AND CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE = 

    (  SELECT MAX(TO_CHAR(CCSREVEFFECTIVEDATE,'dd/MM/yyyy')) 

        FROM CCS2_TBL_MASTERLIST  ) 

ORDER BY CCSMASTERLISTREVNO DESC;
```

Btw, TQ in advance. =p

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks OK; though, I'd remove TO_CHAR call, it seems unnecessary & inappropriate. Also, depending on a tool you use, empty lines between might cause the problem. Try with such a query:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ccsmasterlistrevno,
                  ccsrevcontent,
                  ccspreparedrev,
                  ccsreveffectivedate
    FROM ccs2_tbl_masterlist
   WHERE     ccsequipmentdpmt = :dpmt
         AND ccsmasterlistrevno <= :revno
         AND ccsreveffectivedate =
                (SELECT MAX (ccsreveffectivedate) FROM ccs2_tbl_masterlist)
ORDER BY ccsmasterlistrevno DESC;
```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio. It still didn't work with that

Comment: As I said: query looks OK. Try to execute it line-by-line, i.e. first run `select ccsmasterlistrevno from ccs2_tbl_masterlist;` and see whether it works. Then add `where ccsequipmentdpmt = :dpmt` and run it again, and so forth.